# Swift iOS MapKit Polylines - creating a grid

Tags: ios, mapkit, polyline

I am attempting to draw a grid using polylines in the viewable area of the map. However, although the lines are drawn they seem to flicker and disappear at times. I have been through different approaches but all seem to suffer the same problem.

I have done this through the map view delegate mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion, if existing poly lines are their then I remove them and draw new ones across the viewable region.

Below is the delegate code I just can't seem to pin point why the lines disappear.

```
    func mapViewDidChangeVisibleRegion(_ mapView: MKMapView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let zoomLevel = mapView.getZoomLevel()

        if(mapView.overlays.count > 0)
        {
            for line in mapView.overlays
            {
                mapView.removeOverlay(line)
            }
        }

        let northEast = mapView.convert(CGPoint(x: mapView.bounds.width, y: 0), toCoordinateFrom: mapView)
        let southWest = mapView.convert(CGPoint(x: 0, y: mapView.bounds.height), toCoordinateFrom: mapView)


        let minLon = 10 * Int((floor(southWest.longitude) / 10.0).rounded())
        let maxLon = 10 * Int((floor(northEast.longitude) / 10.0).rounded())

        let minLat = 10 * Int((floor(southWest.latitude) / 10.0).rounded())
        let maxLat = 10 * Int((floor(northEast.latitude) / 10.0).rounded())



        if(zoomLevel < 6)
        {

            for latIndex in stride(from: minLat, through: maxLat, by: 10)
            {
                var pointsLon : [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
                if(minLon < 0 && maxLon  < 0)
                {
                    let startPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(minLon))
                    pointsLon.append(startPos)


                    let endPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(maxLon))
                    pointsLon.append(endPos)
                }
                if(minLon > 0 && maxLon > 0)
                {
                    let startPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(minLon))
                    pointsLon.append(startPos)


                    let endPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(maxLon))
                    pointsLon.append(endPos)
                }
                if(minLon < 0 && maxLon > 0 )
                {
                    let startPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(maxLon))
                    pointsLon.append(startPos)

                    let midPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(0))
                    pointsLon.append(midPos)

                    let endPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(minLon))
                    pointsLon.append(endPos)
                }
                if(minLon > 0 && maxLon < 0 )
                {
                    let sPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(maxLon))
                    pointsLon.append(sPos)

                    let mPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(-180))
                    pointsLon.append(mPos)

                    let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: pointsLon, count: pointsLon.count)
                    self.polylines.append(polyline)
                    mapView.addOverlay(polyline, level: .aboveRoads )

                    pointsLon.removeAll()

                    let startPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(minLon))
                    pointsLon.append(startPos)

                    let midPos = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(CLLocationDegrees(latIndex), CLLocationDegrees(180))
                    pointsLon.append(midPos)
                }

                let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: pointsLon, count: pointsLon.count)
                self.polylines.append(polyline)
                mapView.addOverlay(polyline, level: .aboveRoads )

            }

        }
        else if(zoomLevel < 12)
        {
            //to be implemented
        }
        else{
            //to be implemented
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why is gratefully recieved. Running on iOS 12.1 and iPhone 8 and emulator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem needs to debug and test some ways, I try it; But I need to know something you want do exactly. "You want to show a grid on your map and also showing one or more points on your map while the grid is visible" Is it right?

Comment: Hi yes, the grid would be the Maidenhead locator and at different zoom levels show locators fat either one, two or three pair. Such as IO, IO91 and IO91SM the grid would be direct sizes at these levels hence dynamically plotting the lines I have only put in the longitudinal lines at the moment which is where I am seeing the problem thanks